# Are long-lived SSL/TLS certificates acceptable for non-public resources?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Our organization maintains a private certificate authority to issue SSL/TLS certificates to non-public backend services running on our cloud infrastructure. For example, Postgres and Elasticsearch servers running on a private vnet.

Currently we issue these certificates with a 2 year expiry, but the renewal process is manual and we don't have the resources to work on automating it. Given the certificates are only used within a private vnet, are there any significant risks associated with extending the expiry to 5 or 10 years?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik, [1 year limit](https://casecurity.org/2020/07/09/one-year-certs/) is only for CAs that participate in CAB Forum. Compliant clients differentiate public CAs and private CAs and apply different rules. That is, compliant browsers won't alert on a 2yr TLS certificate from private CA (as long as it is trusted). A quote from CAB Forum page:

> You might also consider moving some certificates from public to private trust, which also helps with management – you could even issue certs with longer validity using that method.